# In Emacs, is there a way to Call Interactive Function non-interactively from init.el?

Tags: sql, emacs, elisp

Is it possible, in general, to call an interactive function from init.el, if it's parameters are known?

Let me give a concrete example: In the sql package, there is a interactive function *sql-connect*.

When invoked as

```
    M-x sql-connect
```

it asks for Connection in the minibuffer. Answering

```
    my-mysql-localhost-connection1
```

opens an *SQL* buffer with mysql prompt which it what I want.

I would like to start the connection in a *SQL* buffer on Emacs startup. But adding, in my init.el:

```
   (sql-connect 'my-mysql-localhost-connection1)
```

does not do anything. Is what I am trying to achieve possible in this case, and for a general interactive function (which parameters are known)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general:

Yes, and you can use `repeat-complex-command` (<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>M-:</kbd>) after the interactive call to find out what the arguments ended up looking like. This is a useful approach to remember, because sometimes there are hidden manipulations in an interactive form which can transform the user's input into something different<sup>1</sup>.

That doesn't *necessarily* give you the best arguments to use in a non-interactive call (that will always be dependent on the function in question), but it's probably the best place to start if you're unsure how to translate the one to the other<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> `align-regexp` is a good example of this.
<sup>2</sup> Assuming that you've at least read the docstring for the function in question -- it's not uncommon for a given interactive command to be the wrong thing to call in a non-interactive context, and the function help is usually good enough to point this out.

Comment: Your solution solved my problem, and the repeat-complex-command is the solution path.

- First I did sql-connect interactively.
- Then I did repeat-complex-comment  `(C-x M-:)`
- This resulted in showing: Redo: (sql-connect "my-mysql-localhost-connection1" nil) [which has a **second argument** nil at the end which was never asked for interactively]
- So I plugged in init.el: (sql-connect "my-mysql-localhost-connection1" nil) ;  this works - Thanks!

Comment: On more testing, it appears the difference was not the additional nil parameter, but the fact the first parameter should be `"my-mysql-localhost-connection1"` (string) rather than `'my-mysql-localhost-connection1`. Still your solution solved the problem.

Comment: Glad that helped. It does suggest that there's a bug -- the documentation for `sql-connection-alist` states that CONNECTION should be a symbol, not a string; however I can confirm that setting it via the customize interface in results in a string (Emacs 24.3). Whether the problem is with the documentation or with the customize widget, I couldn't say.

Comment: btw, you should 'accept' an answer at some point, if the problem is resolved to your satisfaction.

Comment: n.b. http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13715#20 says this was a documentation error, and CONNECTION should indeed be a string.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your general question is yes: you can invoke an interactive function from code, instead of using `M-x`.

Wrt your more specific question:

You should not need to call the function interactively (i.e., no need to use `call-interactively`) unless for some reason you really want to invoke it interactively for some reason (e.g., to prompt the user). ;-)

Just call it by supplying the necessary arguments, and you should be OK. IOW this should work:

```
 (sql-connect 'my-mysql-localhost-connection1)
```

But the doc says that the `CONNECTION` arg must define actual connection settings, per `sql-connection-alist`.  Check that `my-mysql-localhost-connection1` does follow  `sql-connection-alist` in defining connection settings properly so that the user is not prompted for any login parameters.

Comment: Yes, I am calling sql-connest from init.el as 

    (sql-connect 'my-mysql-localhost-connection1)

But that does not make the connection. `my-mysql-localhost-connection1` is setup purely through customize. When I call `sql-connect from M-x` and answer the "Connection" prompt, everything works (no further prompts and the connection is made). I cannot find anything in the customize definition of my-mysql-localhost-connection1 that would not be defined properly. (If that was the case, I assume calling `sql-connect from M-x` would also ask or not be able to connect.)

Comment: Also, once in emacs (not in init.el), if I run: `M-: (sql-connect 'my-mysql-localhost-connection1)` it just answers `nil` and does not do anything (no buffer opened, no connection)

Comment: This shows that `my-mysql-localhost-connection1` is not a good arg. You need an arg that includes the login info too, because you are not interacting with user (prompt + input). Look into `sql-connect`, to see just what it expects as arg. See `sql-connection-alist` and `sql-read-connection`. What the latter returns is what you need to provide as arg for your call. That is the `car` of an element of `sql-connection-alist` or similar. Try (a) first doing it interactively, then (b) seeing what the value of `sql-connection-history` is. That is the value you need to use as arg.

Comment: This lead to a solution as well. I have first managed to solve it using (another post suggested) C-x M-: but then I tried your suggestion as well: `describe-variable sql-connection-history`. That responded  `"my-mysql-localhost-connection1"` (string) rather than `'my-mysql-localhost-connection1` which I kept using. So your suggestion also solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: this also helped solve my question but I can only accept one answer